# Start Graphical Interface

Tags: debian, command-line, gnome, root, gdm3

I recently subscribed for a cloud company and launched application server under debian 10.5

I wanna go from command-line to graphical interface, but I can´t I typed startx , but I got.

[image]
I tried using

```
tasksel install desktop kde-desktop
systemctl set-default graphical.target
also edited: nano /etc/pam.d/gdm-password with
```

#auth  required  pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
4)sudo reboot

---

I also tried

- tasksel
- dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
- sudo apt-get install gdm3
- nano /etc/X11/default-display-manager
- /usr/sbin/gdm3
- sudo systemctl reboot
- typed startx

and also got (the picture)

but I cannot see the graphical mode

Comment: Hello! Great to have you here! Are you *sure* you want to run the X server on the remote server? Usually, the X Server is on the machine that has the actual screen, and the client programs are those displaying thing on that. But: there's also use cases for special X server configurations (which incorporate virtual(ized) graphic card buffers) running on headless servers. **I'm just really not sure you're doing what you want to achieve here!** Please explain what exactly you want to be able to do after you've made your X server run.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please revise your post to fix the formatting (code formatting and list formatting) to make it easier to read. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on how to use the formatting tools.

Comment: As an aside, please take the time to type out error messages. Posting a photograph of your screen is advised against by Stack Exchange's guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wanna connect to Remote connection, but I need the graphical Interface when I start the Remote connection automatically. Thanks

Comment: [This](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1065788-start-0.html) is from another forum but it can help you.

Comment: @ThinLizzy sadly I don't understand what that means! It's not clear to me what "connect to Remote connection" means, and what you want to do with this. I think you really have it backwards where the X server is supposed to run, but I'm still not sure. Could you maybe explain your *use case*. Like "I want to run libreoffice on that cloud machine, but I want its windows to be displayed on my local machine", or "I want to run a browser on my local machine, but have them be visible on an X server that others can observe remotely". Or something else! It's really not clear to me :(

Comment: yes  "I want to run libreoffice on that cloud machine, but I want its windows to be displayed on my local machine.  But for the default the cloud company gives me the command-line, when I try to connect Remote, that is why I need the graphical Interface to start automatically

Comment: Then you likely don't want to run an X server (especially not as root!) on the remote machine at all! instead, you need to run one locally, and then you can do something like `ssh -Y cloudmashine libreoffice`. Or maybe you want to run a VNC server there?

Comment: not just need the graphical interface start automatically on that machine  independently  if i run libreoffice or any other application.

Comment: that has nothing to do with running an X server.

Comment: yes but I don´.t know the screen shows me that message when I typed startx to wake up the graphical mode.

Comment: you're throwing terminology and terms together that just make no sense, sorry.

Comment: Oh I am sorry thanks for your patience.

Comment: Cloud servers are not meant for that use case (running desktop apps). They are meant to run server software such as Apache, sshd, ftpd, mail server etc. I suggest referring to the support service of your cloud provider for further details.

Comment: Most likely you want to run some storage server program a la Google Drive (but your own) on your cloud server and then connect to your server from your desktop.

Comment: oh Thanks for clarify  the idea.